# Python/SQLITE: How do I escape commands/strings

Tags: python, string, sqlite, sql-injection

I would like to construct a sqlite3 database query in python, then write it to a file.

I am a huge fan of python's interfaces for sql databases, which AFAICT wrap all calls you could mess up with a nice little '?' parameters that sanitizes/escapes your strings for you, but that's not what I want. I actually just want to prepare and escape a sql statement - to do this, I need to escape/quote arbitrary strings.

For example:

```
query = "INSERT INTO example_table VALUES ('%s')",sqlite_escape_string("'")
```

And so query should contain:
"INSERT INTO example_table VALUES ('''')"

Note that it inserted an additional ' character.

PHP's equivalent is sqlite_escape_string()
perl's equivalent is DBI's quote()
I feel Python has a better overall interface, but I happen to need the query, pre-exec.

Comment: If you only want to escape the string and *not* execute a query, wouldn't a regular expression take care of that?

Comment: A replace regex would do it, although I'd rather not reimplement the wheel - I know python internally is doing this(or maybe the c SQLite library).

Comment: Right - using qmark or parameterized notations will escape the strings properly (or at least, as best as I've seen).  I would like you to clarify - are you not executing queries with these statements?  What is the main reason to avoid using qmark/parameters?

Comment: I am not executing the queries, only preparing them in final text form, ready to be sent to the database.

Comment: Can I use the paramterized notation outside of the DB-api? It seems that would have to be db specific?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you could use the parameterized notation outside of the DB-API, but I don't believe it's isolated to a single database, either.  Check [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq) reference for the DB API.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do, and what "escape the string" means (what string??), **with examples** of input text and expected output text.

Comment: I've updated it, let me know if anything is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use SQLite it doesn't turn parameterized queries back into text.  It has an api ("bindings") and stores the values separately.  Queries can be reused with different values just by changing the bindings.  This is what underlies the statement cache.  Consequently you'll get no help from python/sqlite in doing what you describe.

What you didn't describe is why you want to do this.  The usual reason is as some form of tracing.  My alternate Python/SQLite interface (APSW) provides easy tracing - you don't even have to touch your code to use it:

https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/execution.html#apsw-trace

SQLite also has an authorizer API which lets you veto operations performed by a statement.  This also has a side effect of telling you what operations a statement would end up performing.

Comment: I just want to prepare some statements for later use. I had assumed they wrapped sqlite3_exec() from the C api, which would require preparing a statement, but I haven't really looked into how the bindings work.

Comment: It looks like it is using sqlite3_prepare(), so the binding is constructing a sanitized query and running it through the C api. I was hoping this was somehow exposed to the end users, as it is in Perl's DBI quote() or php's sqlite_escape_string().

Comment: Your mental model of how SQLite works does not remotely match how it does actually work!  There is no quoting, "sanitized queries" or anything similar involved.  If you want to save queries then save the SQL text and the bindings.  The pickle module can do this for you.  SQLite does have a function available for printing with quoting but neither of the Python wrappers bother because it is so pointless.

Comment: But I don't want a pickle, I want a SQL statement, with everything substituted in and ready to execute, so I could write it to a plain text file.

Comment: I see - pysqlite is using the sqlite3_bind_* interface - I'm not terribly familiar with the C api, but it looks like this lets you assemble the parts of the statement, without copying around large BLOBs or TEXT chunks into a single contiguous statement, and it lets sqlite3 handle quoting and such for you.

Comment: You cannot get exactly what you described with the SQLite wrappers to Python.  You can either achieve the goals by using pickle or stop using SQLite.  The way SQLite works internally is that statements are compiled to an internal program (VDBE).  Bindings are parameters to that program.  There is no quoting etc going on.  As I keep saying SQLite does not work the way you keep wanting it to.  Your choice is to do things the SQLite way or use something else.